# How to generate AWS credentials automatically through AWS SDK JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi I am working on IAM roles and these have temporary credentials generated for every one hour. I have to run awstokens.exe for every one hour to update the sessiontoken; aws security key, token. So I am working on API which will publish the custom metrics to cloudwatch but it requires credentials for every one hour. As I have done with this API I want to automate this on remote linux server. So how to auto generate the AWS credentials?

I invoked AWS SDK JAVA API and wrote my own API but want to automatically generate the credentials.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not real sure what you're trying to accomplish, but can you just use the temporary credentials provided through the IAM instance role? You can use the ProfileCredentialsProvider class.